# self.tableView not recognized as a UITableView, but rather a random method

Tags: uitableview, swift

I'm struggling with xCode for hours, over a very simple issue. I'm subclassing UITableViewController, and in the scrollViewDidScroll method, I try to access my visible tableview rows, as such:

```
class ShinySubclass: UITableViewController {
    override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let visibleIndexPaths : [NSIndexPath] = self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows()
        ...
    }
}
```

although I get this lovely message, pointing to self.*t*ableView:

> ShinySubclass.swift:58:48: '(UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int)
>   -> Int' does not have a member named 'indexPathsForVisibleRows'

This seems like an xCode bug to me. I've got the latest version (Version 6.1 (6A1052d)), and I've tried anything from clean, rebuild, turn room lights on/off etc...

Any ideas how to get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexPathsForVisibleRows` returns `[AnyObject]?`, but you are trying to assign to a non optional `[NSIndexPath]` variable. If you just let type inference do the job the code compiles:

```
let visibleIndexPaths  = self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows()
```

That returns an array of `AnyObject`, so probably you want to downcast to the proper type, but in this case a downcast is needed:

```
let visibleIndexPaths = self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows() as? [NSIndexPath]
```

However, since I presume you want to do some processing if that array is not `nil`, and taking into account that `indexPathsForVisibleRows` can return nil if no row is visible, you can use optional binding:

```
if let visibleIndexPaths = self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows() as? [NSIndexPath] {
    ...   
}
```

In this case `visibleIndexPaths` is a non optional array `[NSIndexPath]`

Comment: That worked! xCode really needs to improve its error messages for swift... I can't make the connection between the mistake I made and the error message I got.

Comment: Yeah that's a common problem with the swift compiler. I think it can be explained by the fact that type inference is trying to locate a method returning `[NSIndexPath]`, which of course doesn't exist.

Comment: Could be worse.  Some things that should generate an error and refuse to build instead attempt to compile and hit a segfault (the compiler segfaults).